# Haskell and function composition

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I was learning some basic function composition in Haskell and while I was playing around I realised something I cannot really explain. When I use the following block of code the compiler seems to be happy about it and works fine:

```
doSomeX x = if x==7 then True else False
doSomeY (x,y) = x+y+1
doSomeXY = doSomeX.doSomeY
```

However when I split the doSomeY into 2 args instead of a pair, i.e.:

```
doSomeX x = if x==7 then True else False
doSomeY x y = x+y+1
doSomeXY = doSomeX.doSomeY
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of `doSomeY'
 The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
 Relevant bindings include
   doSomeXY :: a0 -> Bool (bound at test.hs:21:1)
 Note: there are several potential instances:
   instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
     -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
   instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
   instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
   ...plus three others
 In the second argument of `(.)', namely `doSomeY'
 In the expression: doSomeX . doSomeY
 In an equation for `doSomeXY': doSomeXY = doSomeX . doSomeY
```

I don't really see why though. On both cases the return type of the `doSomeY` is the same type with that of the arg of the function `doSomeX` why would the input type of `doSomeY` would make a difference? Am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see why with the equivalent `doSomeY x = \y -> x + y + 1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is caused by `doSomeY` yielding a number in the first case vs. yielding a function in the second case when applied to one argument.

Given

```
doSomeX x = if x==7 then True else False
doSomeY x y = x+y+1
```

we can infer the types (these aren't the most generic types possible, but they'll do for our purposes):

```
doSomeX :: Int -> Bool
doSomeY :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Remember that `->` in type signature associates to the right, so the type of `doSomeY` is equivalent to

```
doSomeY :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

With this in mind, consider the type of `(.)`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

If you define

```
doSomeXY = doSomeX.doSomeY
```

...which is equivalent to `(.) doSomeX doSomeY`, it means that the first argument to `(.)` is `doSomeX` and the second argument is `doSomeY`. Hence, the type `b -> c` (the first argument to `(.)`) must match the type `Int -> Bool` (the type of `doSomeX`). So

```
b ~ Int
c ~ Bool
```

Hence,

```
(.) doSomeX :: (a -> Int) -> a -> Bool
```

Now, applying this to `doSomeY` causes a type error. As mentioned above,

```
doSomeY :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

So when inferring a type for `(.) doSomeX doSomeY` the compiler has to unify `a -> Int` (the first argument of `(.) doSomeX`) with `Int -> (Int -> Int)` (the type of `doSomeY`). `a` can be unified with `Int`, but the second half won't work. Hence the compiler barfs.

Answer (score 3):

`(.)` is defined as

```
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

so `(f . g) x y = (.) f g x y = f (g x) y`, not `f (g x y)` like you intended.

On the other hand, `(f . g) (x,y) = f (g (x,y))`, because `(x,y)` is *one* value,  a 2-tuple, so your first version is okay.